# MYSQL REGEX search many words with no order condition

Tags: mysql, regex, database

I try to use a regex with mysql that search boundary words in a json array string but I don't want the regex match words order because I don't know them.

So I started firstly to write my regex on regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/wNVyaZ/1) and then try to convert this one for mysql.

```sql
WHERE `Wish`.`services` REGEXP '^([^>].*[[:<:]]Hygiène[[:>:]])([^>].*[[:<:]]Radiothérapie[[:>:]]).+';
```

```sql
WHERE `Wish`.`services` REGEXP '^([^>].*[[:<:]]Hygiène[[:>:]])([^>].*[[:<:]]Andrologie[[:>:]]).+';
```

In the first query I get result, cause "Hygiène" is before "Radiothérapie" but in the second query "Andrologie" is before "Hygiène" and not after like it written in the query. The problem is that the query is generated automatically with a list of services that are choosen with no order importance and I want to match only boundary words if they exists no matter the order they have.

Comment: What are you asking for? If the query is generated automatically, can you change the code that generates the query?

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON that you are trying to search? It's hard to know what you mean by boundary words. It's best if you show some examples of data that should satisfy your search and some examples that don't satisfy the search.

Comment: Bill Karwin You can look in the regex101 link that I've share, this is the string that I'm searching on : `"[\"Andrologie\",\"Angiologie\",\"Hygiène\",\"Radiothérapie\"]"`

Comment: And it's only based on this string, but the result change depending the words order in the regex. So I just want to trigger this string with regexp no matter the order of the words in the regex.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 5.7 or 8.0? There are functions to work with JSON data that would be able to search for specific values more easily, without using REGEXP. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search

Comment: I'm on v5.7, thanks for the information about 8.0 but is there any way to do it in 5.7 with REGEXP function ?

Comment: You just want to select every word in the array? Like this: https://regex101.com/r/aAasf8/1 ? Or do you want to search for specific words like this https://regex101.com/r/MutFvz/2 ?

Comment: @glhr None of these example, it's mostly looks like the second example but instead of OR operator (`|`) I want a AND operator to get regex true if "Hygiène" and "Andrologie" are both in the string and not one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for words in JSON like the following (I tested on MySQL 5.7):

```
select * from wish 
where json_search(services, 'one', 'Hygiène') is not null 
  and json_search(services, 'one', 'Andrologie') is not null;

+------------------------------------------------------------+
| services                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["Andrologie", "Angiologie", "Hygiène", "Radiothérapie"]   |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I now use mysql 8 and the request 
```sql
SELECT * FROM `Wishes` WHERE json_search(services, 'one', 'Hygiène');
```
or 
```sql
SELECT * FROM `Wishes` WHERE json_search(services, 'one', 'Hygiène') is not null 
  AND json_search(services, 'one', 'Andrologie') is not null;
``` 
doesn't return anything

Comment: Why is that? Could it be there is no row where both words occur in the same JSON document in your data?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use the JSON search queries (you need a MySQL with JSON support).

If it's advisable, consider changing the database structure and enter the various "words" as a related table. This would allow you much more powerful (and faster) queries.

```
JOIN has_service AS hh ON (hh.row_id = id)
JOIN services AS ss ON (hh.service_id = ss.id
       AND ss.name IN ('Hygiène', 'Angiologie', ...)
```

Otherwise, in this context, consider that you're not really doing a regexp search, and you're doing a full table scan *anyway* (unless MySQL 8.0+ or PerconaDB 5.7+ (not sure) *and* an index on the full extent of the 'services' column), and several LIKE queries will actually cost you *less*:

```
WHERE (services LIKE '%"Hygiène"%'
    OR services LIKE '%"Angiologie"%'
    ...)
```

or

```
 IF(services LIKE '%"Hygiène"%', 1, 0)
+IF(services LIKE '%"Angiologie"%', 1, 0)
+ ... AS score

HAVING score > 0 -- or score=5 if you want only matches on all full five
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'll consider changing my json format to use your first solution.